# json array shows in logacat with no errors but does not show in android view

Tags: java, android, json

[image]A large part of my app is grabbing data from a website. The data shows in my logcat, green with no errors but will not display in my android view. Ive tried and searched for a week or and have had no luck.
here is my class.

```
public class Json extends ListActivity {


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonParser = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

ListView lv ;
private static final String jsonFilePath = "http://xda.olinksoftware.com/leaderboard/all";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.json);


    new ProgressTask(Json.this).execute();
 }

  private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

private ProgressDialog dialog;

   public ProgressTask(Json json) {

   Log.i("1", "Called");
   context = json;
   dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
  }


  private Context context;


   protected void onPreExecute() {
   this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
   this.dialog.show();
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }



        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonParser,
                R.layout.listitem, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SCORE,
                 }, new int[] {
                        R.id.score, R.id.name, 
     });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
         lv = getListView();


    }



    @Override
   protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

       new JSONParser();




       try {
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    String jsonString = "";
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    try{
                        URL url = new URL(jsonFilePath);
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                        int read;
                        char[] chars = new char[1024];
                        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                            buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
                    }finally {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                    }   

                    jsonString = buffer.toString();
                    try{
                        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                        JSONArray leaderboard = (JSONArray)jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
                        for(int i = 0;i<leaderboard.size();i++){
                            JSONObject user = (JSONObject)leaderboard.get(i);
                            System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + user.get("forumName") + " (" + user.get("score") + ")");                            
                        }
                    }catch(ParseException pe){
                        System.out.println("position: " + pe.getPosition());
                        System.out.println(pe);
                    }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }}  

  }
```

and here are my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- Main ListView 
     Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
-->
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
<TextView
android:id="@+id/name"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone" />

  <!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
android:id="@+id/score"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="6dp"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:textSize="17sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

any help is greatly appreciated. I know I am doing something wrong with my listview as it also works as a straight java application run in eclipse.

here is the data i am grabbing, i am only taking two values at this time. "forumUser" and "score"

```
[{"userId":"3579348","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=3579348","forumName":"newtoroot","totalPosts":"5074","postsPerDay":"5.14","totalThanks":"18302","joinDate":"2011-01-29","yearsJoined":"2","referrals":"4","friendCount":"38","recognizedDeveloper":"1","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"48","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"1","themeCount":"0","score":"302","userName":"","password":""},{"userId":"1596076","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=1596076","forumName":"il Duce","totalPosts":"16335","postsPerDay":"9.75","totalThanks":"15799","joinDate":"2009-02-25","yearsJoined":"4","referrals":"2","friendCount":"83","recognizedDeveloper":"1","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"1","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"1","kernelCount":"1","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"0","themeCount":"0","score":"132","userName":"","password":""},{"userId":"2930301","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=2930301","forumName":"fernando sor","totalPosts":"8967","postsPerDay":"7.93","totalThanks":"4549","joinDate":"2010-09-07","yearsJoined":"3","referrals":"2","friendCount":"29","recognizedDeveloper":"0","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"1","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"1","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"5","modCount":"2","themeCount":"15","score":"120","userName":"fernando sor","password":""},{"userId":"3220669","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=3220669","forumName":"1975jamie","totalPosts":"582","postsPerDay":"0.56","totalThanks":"127","joinDate":"2010-11-23","yearsJoined":"2","referrals":"0","friendCount":"0","recognizedDeveloper":"1","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"4","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"0","themeCount":"0","score":"46","userName":"1975jamie","password":""},{"userId":"2552854","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=2552854","forumName":"jeffsanace","totalPosts":"2797","postsPerDay":"2.25","totalThanks":"2836","joinDate":"2010-05-05","yearsJoined":"3","referrals":"0","friendCount":"12","recognizedDeveloper":"0","recognizedContributor":"1","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"0","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"0","themeCount":"0","score":"37","userName":"","password":""},{"userId":"2067958","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=2067958","forumName":"eg1122","totalPosts":"1200","postsPerDay":"0.82","totalThanks":"1695","joinDate":"2009-10-05","yearsJoined":"3","referrals":"0","friendCount":"6","recognizedDeveloper":"0","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"0","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"2","themeCount":"0","score":"20","userName":"","password":""},{"userId":"3042344","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=3042344","forumName":"dfuse06","totalPosts":"3331","postsPerDay":"3.08","totalThanks":"2270","joinDate":"2010-10-11","yearsJoined":"2","referrals":"1","friendCount":"29","recognizedDeveloper":"0","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"0","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"1","themeCount":"0","score":"17","userName":"","password":""},{"userId":"1070340","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=1070340","forumName":"chrisloveskaos","totalPosts":"215","postsPerDay":"0.11","totalThanks":"8","joinDate":"2008-07-08","yearsJoined":"5","referrals":"0","friendCount":"7","recognizedDeveloper":"0","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"1","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"0","themeCount":"0","score":"14","userName":"","password":""},{"userId":"2688514","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=2688514","forumName":"GooTz66","totalPosts":"999","postsPerDay":"0.84","totalThanks":"70","joinDate":"2010-06-25","yearsJoined":"3","referrals":"0","friendCount":"7","recognizedDeveloper":"0","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"0","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"0","themeCount":"0","score":"7","userName":"","password":""},{"userId":"2141845","userURL":"http:\/\/forum.xda-developers.com\/member.php?u=2141845","forumName":"Kush.Kush\u00c2\u0099","totalPosts":"86","postsPerDay":"0.06","totalThanks":"0","joinDate":"2009-11-09","yearsJoined":"3","referrals":"0","friendCount":"16","recognizedDeveloper":"0","recognizedContributor":"0","recognizedThemer":"0","moderator":"0","recognizedEliteDeveloper":"0","romCount":"0","kernelCount":"0","tutorialCount":"0","modCount":"0","themeCount":"0","score":"6","userName":"","password":""}]
```

Comment: Where did you actually expect the json data to appear? I don't see any interaction with your list view, have you included all your code? You need to set an adapter for the list view to "translate" your data into something that can be displayed on a list. For example, parse your JSONArray into a JSONObject[] and use an ArrayAdapter on your List view.

Comment: would you please put a sample of the JSON text returned from the web ?
And you provided the code for fetching the JSON data ,, where is the code where you add it to listVIew

Comment: yeah i tried adding an adapter. i obviously did it wrong. would you happen to have any sample code?

Comment: thats where i am stuck. i cant seem to bind it to my listview. i want this to diplay a running list which it is doing in java.

Comment: victor will i need another xml or will the listview work with the adapter?

Comment: and yes that is all of my code

Comment: updated with adapter and new xml. still does not fc and no errors in logcat. same as picture above

Answer (score 0):

Why is this line

```
     setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Before this

```
    // selecting single ListView item
     lv = getListView();
```

Also, the LogCat you posted is showing the results using the "info" filter only. Try looking at the verbose view to make sure no exceptions that you're missing.

Comment: i changed the order on the get ListView. thanks for that. also the i am looking at the verbose view and it is the same as i posted above.

Answer (score 0):

what i did to solve this was pretty much start over. i added a JSONParser class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONArray jarray = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
          } else {
            Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
          }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jarray = new JSONArray( builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
return jarray;
```

and a JsonActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private static String url = "website";

private static final String TAG_VTYPE = "forumName";
private static final String TAG_VCOLOR = "score";
private static final String TAG_THANKS = "totalThanks";
private static final String TAG_POSTS = "totalPosts";
private static final String TAG_JOIN_DATE = "joinDate";
private static final String TAG_ROM_COUNT = "romCount";
private static final String TAG_THEME_COUNT = "themeCount";
private static final String TAG_MOD_COUNT = "modCount";
private static final String TAG_KERNEL_COUNT = "kernelCount";
private static final String TAG_TUTORIAL_COUNT = "tutorialCount";
private static final String TAG_DEV = "recognizedDeveloper";
private static final String TAG_THEMER = "recognizedThemer";
private static final String TAG_MODERATOR = "moderator";
private static final String TAG_RDEV = "recognizedEliteDeveloper";
private static final String TAG_RCOD = "recognizedContributor";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private View header;
ListView lv ;
LayoutInflater Inflater;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
    Inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;



    private ListActivity activity;

    // private List<Message> messages;
    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    }

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */
    private Context context;


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }



        View header = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view_name, null);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_VTYPE, TAG_VCOLOR, TAG_THANKS, TAG_POSTS, TAG_JOIN_DATE, TAG_ROM_COUNT,
                TAG_THEME_COUNT, TAG_MOD_COUNT, TAG_KERNEL_COUNT, TAG_DEV, TAG_TUTORIAL_COUNT, TAG_THEMER, TAG_MODERATOR, TAG_RDEV, TAG_RCOD,
                         }, new int[] {
                        R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor, R.id.totalThanks, R.id.totalPosts, R.id.joinDate, R.id.romCount,
                        R.id.themeCount, R.id.kernelCount, R.id.modCount, R.id.tutorialCount, R.id.moderator, R.id.rThemer, R.id.rDev,
                        R.id.rCon, R.id.rEliteDev,
                        });


        lv = getListView();

        lv.addHeaderView(header);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item


        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                         ;

        @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
              long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
                String forumName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vehicleType)).getText().toString();
                String score = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vehicleColor)).getText().toString();
                String totalThanks = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totalThanks)).getText().toString();
                String totalPosts = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totalPosts)).getText().toString();
                String joinDate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.joinDate)).getText().toString();
                String romCount = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.romCount)).getText().toString();               
                String themeCount = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.themeCount)).getText().toString();
                String kernelCount = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kernelCount)).getText().toString();
                String modCount = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.modCount)).getText().toString();   
                String tutorialCount = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tutorialCount)).getText().toString();
                String moderator = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moderator)).getText().toString();
                String recognizedThemer = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rThemer)).getText().toString();
                String recognizedDeveloper = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rDev)).getText().toString();
                String recognizedContributor = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rCon)).getText().toString();
                String recognizedEliteDeveloper = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rEliteDev)).getText().toString();





                // Starting new intent





                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_VTYPE, forumName);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_VCOLOR, score);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_THANKS, totalThanks);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_POSTS, totalPosts);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_JOIN_DATE, joinDate);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_ROM_COUNT, romCount);           
                    in.putExtra(TAG_THEME_COUNT, themeCount);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_MOD_COUNT, modCount);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_KERNEL_COUNT, kernelCount);

                    in.putExtra(TAG_TUTORIAL_COUNT, tutorialCount);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_DEV, recognizedDeveloper);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_THEMER, recognizedThemer);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_MODERATOR, moderator);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_RDEV, recognizedEliteDeveloper);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_RCOD, recognizedContributor);







                    startActivity(in);              


                        }});}




    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String forumName = c.getString(TAG_VTYPE);
                    String score = c.getString(TAG_VCOLOR);
                    String totalThanks = c.getString(TAG_THANKS);
                    String totalPosts = c.getString(TAG_POSTS);
                    String joinDate = c.getString(TAG_JOIN_DATE);
                    String romCount = c.getString(TAG_ROM_COUNT);
                    String themeCount = c.getString(TAG_THEME_COUNT);
                    String modCount = c.getString(TAG_MOD_COUNT);
                    String kernelCount = c.getString(TAG_KERNEL_COUNT);
                    String tutorialCount = c.getString(TAG_TUTORIAL_COUNT);
                    String recognizedDeveloper = c.getString(TAG_DEV);
                    String recognizedThemer = c.getString(TAG_THEMER);
                    String moderator = c.getString(TAG_MODERATOR);
                    String recognizedEliteDeveloper = c.getString(TAG_RDEV);
                    String recognizedContributor = c.getString(TAG_RCOD);



                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_VTYPE, forumName);
                    map.put(TAG_VCOLOR, score);
                    map.put(TAG_THANKS, totalThanks);
                    map.put(TAG_POSTS, totalPosts);
                    map.put(TAG_JOIN_DATE, joinDate);
                    map.put(TAG_ROM_COUNT, romCount);
                    map.put(TAG_THEME_COUNT, themeCount);
                    map.put(TAG_MOD_COUNT, modCount);
                    map.put(TAG_KERNEL_COUNT, kernelCount);
                    map.put(TAG_TUTORIAL_COUNT, tutorialCount);
                    map.put(TAG_DEV, recognizedDeveloper);
                    map.put(TAG_THEMER, recognizedThemer);
                    map.put(TAG_MODERATOR, moderator);
                    map.put(TAG_RDEV, recognizedEliteDeveloper);
                    map.put(TAG_RCOD, recognizedContributor);


                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;

        }}}
```

and tied it together with a list view and xml for all my values. turned out really cool. i added an onclick on each value to show more individual data